# If statement within try/catch to handle format exception

Tags: c#, exception

I'm actually new in C#. I bought a tutorial book for c# beginners yesterday.

There is a text how to handle some easy exceptions like the "Format Exception"

I tried it with the easiest way (try/catch). But when debugging, it looks like the Format Exception comes before it catched by "catch". Here is my code:

```
private void cmdBerechnen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double gehalt, steuersatz, endbetrag;

    try
    {
        gehalt = Convert.ToDouble(tbGehalt.Text);

        if (gehalt <= 12000)
        {
            steuersatz = 12;
        }
        else if (gehalt <= 20000)
        {
            steuersatz = 15;
        }
        else if (gehalt <= 30000)
        {
            steuersatz = 20;
        }
        else
        {
            steuersatz = 25;
        }

        endbetrag = gehalt * steuersatz / 100;

        lblSteuerbetrag.Text = "Steuerbetrag: " + endbetrag + " \n" + "Entsprechen : " + steuersatz + " %";
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        lblSteuerbetrag.Text = "Falsches Format";
    }
}
```

The program works fine -> It calculate like I want. But I want to catch the error of the wrong format (letters, empty box, ...).

Comment: It's not really clear what the problem is.  If the program works fine, what's failing?  If no exception is being caught, then no exception is being thrown in the first place.

Comment: is that `catch` ever executing? Put a break point in there

Comment: "But when debugging, it looks like the Format Exception comes before it catched by "catch"" <-- can you elaborate on this?  You go on to say "The program works fine" which is contradictory to the first statement.

Comment: You might want to consider using `double.TryParse` instead so you don't have to catch an exception.

Comment: the program works fine, if you insert a value which cannot be converted to double it jumps to the catch.. as stated @juharr its simpler to just manage the string value with TryParse, but the point of your code is to learn how try{} catch{} works

Comment: You _should_ be able to just use `catch(FormatException fe)` to catch only format exceptions. But using `TryParse` is generally a better approach.